# Running a Windows graphical app inside a Linux desktop running under WSLg

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wine, rendering

There are many examples of displaying WSL apps in the host Windows environment:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65576810/7991646
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66398613/7991646

What about the opposite? Displaying Windows graphical apps (e.g. Notepad, Excel) inside a Linux desktop running under WSLg (or other).

Starting a Windows app from WSL is simple enough:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47663269/7991646

However steps beyond that are less clear. This is an area where I'm relatively new and have a limited understanding of Windows session rendering. This short article was a helpful intro - https://www.2brightsparks.com/resources/articles/understanding-windows-sessions.pdf

Note I would prefer to avoid an API translator like Wine. Installation on the host Windows machine is critical for more complex apps like MS Excel.

Ideally the solution could be scripted / automated for silent deployment to a pool of individual Windows machines.

Comment: Starting a Windows command from within WSL console will simply launch the Windows application within Windows. WINE would be how you run a Windows application from within the Linux kernel.

Comment: I agree WINE can work for simpler apps, but I'm hoping to find some display-forwarding approach. Perhaps a complex Windows app can be run / rendered on the Windows kernel (session 0?), then "streamed" to WSL or elsewhere.

Comment: Use a Windows virtual machine

Comment: So you want to run Windows applications, rendered on the Windows kernel, streamed to WSL through what WSLg? Why?  Even if that was possible what you want is overly complicated.

Comment: As complicated as it sounds, yes that summarized the process. The reason is, if I can render and stream to WSL, then I avoided displaying anything on the Windows host. That opens the door to headless Windows environments such as containers and avoids Windows VMs entirely. People tend to reflexively say "containers don't support GUI apps", but rendering does occur on the kernel. The issue is access / forwarding. For example, I can easily run interactive GUI sessions over SSH to a Linux Docker container in K8s. Windows / WSL interop could enable something similar for Windows containers in theory

Comment: You might wonder, why not just stream with RDP? Microsoft evidently caught on to that possibility and removed support from Windows Docker images in 2019 forward - https://withinrafael.com/2018/03/09/using-remote-desktop-services-in-containers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhat "negative" answer, but perhaps this research will help you in the right direction (if there is one).

I did some experimenting based on your earlier comment on this topic.  And yes, that experimenting was along the same lines that you mentioned in a comment above regarding RDP.

Let's start by summarizing the problem:

- Graphical applications in Windows are drawn using (I believe) GDI at the base layer, usually with a higher level toolkit/framework, of course.
- Graphical applications in Linux/WSL/WSLg are drawn using Wayland and Xwayland, translated to Windows through the use of RDP.

So WSLg uses the ability of Wayland to output to RDP as its magic-ticket to displaying Linux applications.

And, in theory, we could use RDP to display a Windows application in Linux.  RDP clearly includes the ability to run just a single application, rather than the full desktop.  So, in a theoretical perfect world, we could run something like the Remmina (or other) RDP-client under WSLg to remote a Windows graphical application.

In practice, we're gated by several factors, some technical, but mostly based on licensing and feature restrictions:

- It's interesting that the Windows 7 RDP client used to have the ability to specify an application to run on the remote computer.  In Windows 10 and later, it seems this option has been removed (at least from the client app's GUI).  It's still possible to specify an application to start via one of the methods mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1226772/11810933).
- However, if we try that using either `localhost` or the Windows hostname, we get denied because we already have an active console.
- We can still work around this by using `127.0.0.2` for the host address.  But then we run into a licensing issue.  At least on Windows Pro (and I believe Enterprise), we are denied the ability to run an application using RDP because we are limited to "one connection" using terminal services under these SKUs.  AFAIK, only Windows Server allows multiple connections.

And that's all with just RDP from Windows to itself.  Even if we use Remmina, which under WSL2 would be running inside the WSL2 VM, we're still limited by the number of connections already being maxed out.

Again, there's no *technical* reason why RDP couldn't work for this -- Just licensing limitations, unfortunately.

As far as alternatives go, I'm not aware of any good options.  You'd need for the technology to be able to:

- Remote a single application
- Do so in an off-screen buffer so that the application isn't mirrored on the local desktop in Windows while it is running.
- Have a Windows "server" component
- Have a Linux "client" component

Some theories that just don't tick all the boxes:

- That [Windows Containers hack](https://withinrafael.com/2018/03/09/using-remote-desktop-services-in-containers/) you mentioned in the comments sounds like it would have worked, of course, but is no longer an option (licensing issues, once again).
- VNC only does full-screen, not individual apps.
- Nvidia Gamestream (with a Moonlight client) comes close, but to my knowledge it still requires that the application be mirrored on the desktop.  In theory, you might be able to get around this with a dummy HDMI dongle connected to an nVidia card.  But at that point, you're probably stretching a bit too far.
- If you aren't tied to using applications on the *local* Windows installation, you could probably use a third-party RDP desktop/application service, but you're talking a minimum of $25/month for something like AWS Workspaces.

With that, I'm going to stop rattling off ideas that *won't* work.  Hopefully I'm wrong, of course, and someone has a better answer.  I doubt it, but I'll be happy to be wrong if so.

Comment: Revisiting this topic after a long detour. The full-screen VNC option would be a step in the right direction. Freeware preferred to avoid licensing headaches. Any recommendation on where to start? It looks like other attempts have ran into problems in the [past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57821636/docker-container-windows-connect-via-rdp-or-vnc-client).

Comment: @jrbe228 I've noodled on it a bit more since I saw your comment a few hours ago, but I can't think of anything to try at the moment.  I'll keep thinking about it, and please let me know if you make any progress in the meantime.

Comment: Technically [this](https://github.com/m1k1o/win10-in-docker) solves the problem. It's just very inefficient + requires a separate Windows license + possibly unstable due to multiple levels of nested virtualization.

Comment: I suspect this [image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/garrys1966/rdp/latest/images/sha256-16394b211f0d0b0cfd6112cfbe7bcb1a403822ba94b348e0ccefbfb8f5f394fb?context=explore) was an attempt at enabling an RDP desktop. I pulled the image and tested separately on Docker Desktop and Kubernetes. No luck. Wondering why the repo got a few stars...

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  
https://chat.openai.com/share/e6d180dc-d743-491c-8e83-63ab6d0c7651

Comment: @jrbe228 Are you saying you got it to work using this?  I mean, ChatGPT hallucinate a lot, but it gets it right sometimes as well ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I would have written a much larger self-aggrandizing post if I had gotten it to work :)

Comment: @jrbe228 Bummer.  And ironically, I've been [GPT-hunting](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11810933/notthedr01ds?tab=activity&sort=comments) for a bit.  Too many of those hallucinations *are* being posted as answers ;-)

Comment: Guys, following this all has been great fun, regardless of the results, thanks! :)

Comment: If your Windows app is old enough (Win XP, Win Server 2003), this [container](https://github.com/hectorm/docker-qemu-reactos) has a decent chance of running it graphically: